# Reuse figure from research

Tags: citations, graphics

I want to reuse a figure from research with an Attribution 4.0 International license; I want to contact the author to ask his permission. However, I couldn't find any way to contact him. What should I do?

Comment: Did you try searching the person's name online? Maybe that person has a website where you can get contact  information. If you have tried this, maybe try contacting the journal / publisher (I am guessing the figure came from some publisher) by doing an online search. Tell them "I want to use this figure from <paper name, etc> but I am unable to contact the author. How should I proceed"?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't need any permission.  See https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/